# How do you host a Ruby on Rails application on a local network, so multiple people can access it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, localhost

I'm brand new to RoR and have pretty much 0 experience with it. I have been handed down somebody else's project and I need to find a way to host the application, so people can just access it locally. The application is a spider script/walker script/web scraper whatever you call it. Basically it connects to a website, logs in, retrieves certain data each day and maps it with the previous data. While on the local machine, you use it, go to localhost:3000, and you get the webpage the previous person designed. I was just wondering how I could get that page to be public for the people on our local network, so they could connect to some arbitrary IP and see the same page (it updates daily)?

What I tried doing is making the folder containing the application public to the network, but in order to use it, I would have to make everybody on the network allowed to write to it and each person would have to install RoR to use it. I want to avoid that since it doesn't seem logical, nor is it what I'm trying to do.

Looking at the code, I can reverse engineer and understand what it does, but when it comes to hosting web apps locally or something of that sort, I have never done this before. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT
-This is all being done on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Without knowing how you are launching the application, its difficult to give you a precise answer; but you need to do two things [a] make sure the server is listening on your LAN IP and [b] make sure that port 3000 is not blocked on your network. Update your question with the steps you take to launch the system on the local machine for more detailed answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Since you're on Windows, open up a command line and run `ipconfig` to find out your local IP. It will be listed under 'IP Address'.
2. Tell people in your LAN to access http://192.168.x.x:3000 replacing 192.168.x.x by your IP address from step 1.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: One major thing that I missed, you are windows. On windows u could use [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) and put it behind a load balancer. Although i would suggest hosting it on a UNIX machine :)

Although Running it in  webrick(webrick is the application server for development i.e when u run rails s) will let other users access the website NEVER do the same for a production application. If you want to run this application in production, u need more powerful application servers like [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/install.html). I would suggest you use it with Apache or Nginx instead of stand alone passenger. Once all this is setup others can use your application by entering the IP(xx.xx.xx.xx) also u can ask your system admin to setup a local DNS so your users need not remember the IP address always.

Answer (score 1):

### Description:

While starting Rails Server, we can also setup some options to configure the IP address and also the port number of the site under development environment to host the website in local network. So if we want to change the IP from http://127.0.0.1:3000 to http://192.168.x.x:port (x= 0 to 255 any one number), we can set that in Rails server command! But for this, we will need to find out our current IP address at our current network which will help us to serve the website in local network.

#### So at first step:

We will open our terminal on our PC. For Android user, we need to open Termux app. Then simply type `ifconfig` to get the IP address of our device in the current network. We will get an output like this one (Here I'm using Android device for development. So output might be something different than this one on your PC terminal but the process is same):

```
$ ifconfig
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
lo: flags=XX<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu XXXXX
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.XXX.XXX.XXX
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen XXXX  (UNSPEC)
wlan0: flags=XXXX<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu XXXX
    inet 192.168.1.103  netmask 255.XXX.XXX.XXX  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen XXXX  (UNSPEC)
```

**`X= some numbers with our device credentials which is dummied with this variable`**

If you are using a WiFi router then we will need the **`wlan0`** part to get our device IP. Under wlan0 section there is a subsection of **inet** showing our current IP! **YUP**, we need that IP address **192.168.1.103**! This might be **different for your device and network**. This is the key of this mission! Now we're going to the second important step.

#### So the Second Step is:

That required input command to configure the IP address.

`rails s -b 192.168.1.103 -p 8080`

Here:

1. `rails s` for **rails server**
2. `-b 192.168.1.103` for **bidding the IP address** for customisation from the default IP http://127.0.0.1 which is our localhost address.
3. `-p 8080` for **port** setup. **This part is optional. Default port is 3000**.

This is the process of changing the localhost IP (http://127.0.0.1) to local network IP which will be available for other device of the same network user.

Now our rails app is available in our local network! Other users in the same network will also be able to visit the website while the server command is running. And the link will be **http://192.168.1.103:8080** if you also configure the port number. Otherwise if you have used the command `rails s -b 192.168.1.103` without port configuration the link will be: **http://192.168.1.103:3000**

**Again:** 192.168.1.103 was for my case, your IP address will be different for your device. That will be needed to use for your server and link address.